# svn:externals to replace a subdirectory

Tags: svn

I have a directory in my subversion repository that I'd like to replace with the contents of an external repository.  So on my repository, the path is /toplevel/sites/foo.  I want foo to be pulled from an external repository.  I was able to do that by adding "foo http://other-repository.com/path/to/foo" to svn:externals on /toplevel/sites.  However, this makes it impossible to checkout /toplevel/sites/foo directly.  You have to check out /toplevel/sites and let foo get pulled in recursively.  There is a TON of stuff in /toplevel/sites, so this is suboptimal, and we often have workers working on only one thing in /toplevel/sites.

My second attempt was to make an empty directory in toplevel/sites/foo and add the svn:externals property to foo directly.  This lets you checkout /toplevel/sites/foo but it ends up putting the external thing INSIDE, so the resulting path is /toplevel/sites/foo/foo.  I want just one foo.

How do I set things up so that you can pull ONLY /toplevel/sites/foo and nothing else?

EDIT: I've got it to work by creating an empty foo directory and adding all the top level directories from the remote repository into foo's svn:externals.  It's kind of ugly but luckily there are not that many top level entities.  I'd still like to find a way to make it work without doing that, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Erm, by actually just checking out http://other-repository.com/path/to/foo somewhere? I know of no other way. If you need it at the proper place, you can of course just move it in the `sites` directory previously checked out with `svn co --depth=empty`.

Comment: I guess I didn't phrase it clearly.  I want "svn co http://myrepository.com/toplevel/sites/foo" to work, by pulling in http://other-repository.com/path/to/foo.  It doesn't.  It says there's no such URL as http://myrepository.com/toplevel/sites/foo

Comment: I know what you want, but that cannot be done in another manner / directly. An external isn't an alias or something like that, and are handled client-sided, not server-sided. Maybe someone has made custom server-sided code, but I doubt it. As far as the svn-server knows, your 'foo' directory does not exist, only the client reads the props of the dir & discovers an external.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use svn:externals to checkout multiple different directories or even different repositories altogether.

From the svn book (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html);

Subversion provides support for externals definitions. An externals definition is a mapping of a local directory to the URL—and ideally a particular revision—of a versioned directory. In Subversion, you declare externals definitions in groups using the svn:externals property. You can create or modify this property using svn propset or svn propedit (see the section called “Manipulating Properties”). It can be set on any versioned directory, and its value describes both the external repository location and the client-side directory to which that location should be checked out.

The convenience of the svn:externals property is that once it is set on a versioned directory, everyone who checks out a working copy with that directory also gets the benefit of the externals definition. In other words, once one person has made the effort to define the nested working copy structure, no one else has to bother—Subversion will, after checking out the original working copy, automatically also check out the external working copies.